# IIS Rewrite Safely Add Custom Query String

Tags: iis, iis-7, url-rewriting

I want to move something in a url path out to the query string. This is almost like a subdomain rewrite. Here's what the rewrite should look like:
~/ch-ar/rest -> ~/rest?dom=ch-ar
~/su-bd/rest?param=val -> ~/rest?param=val&dom=su-bd

I can definitely do the first part through matching/replacing isn't something I have been able to account for. I'm not sure if there's some way to safely add my key value pair to the {QUERY_STRING} variable but that would probably be ideal. The key for this name value pair will never change and the order of the query string doesn't matter to me.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the following 2 rules, one for requests that have a query string and one for requests that do not. I have used a language specific URI stem as an example and have set the action to redirect so it is easier to test.

```
            <rule name="Language URI to QS - Existing Query String" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2})(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.+)" />
                </conditions>
                <serverVariables>
                    <set name="QUERY_STRING" value="{C:1}&amp;dom={R:1}" />
                </serverVariables>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{R:2}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Found" />
            </rule>

            <rule name="Language URI to QS - No Query String" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2})(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern=".+" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <serverVariables>
                    <set name="QUERY_STRING" value="dom={R:1}" />
                </serverVariables>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{R:2}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Found" />
            </rule>
```

Comment: This sounds like a pretty good idea although I'll need to look up what negate does. I was hoping I could do this in one rule using a look ahead in the regex and tying the result of there being a '?' in the input to how I appended the language but it doesn't look like I will be able to pull that off.

Comment: The negate inverts the condition:

<conditions>
<add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern=".+" negate="true" />
</conditions>

In plain english: The condition is true if the query string does not contain "something".

For the sake of my sanity I try to keep my rewrites as simple as possible, when you have to sift through dozens of rewrites 6 months down the line...